# How to convert a mixed type array to a char array and back?

Tags: c, pointers, unions

I have to transfer a mixed type array (union) from one uController (source) to another uController (target) via SPI, thus I have to bring the whole transfer chunk into a uint8_t array before transfering and then reconstruct it in the target uC back to the mixed type union array.

I tried following approach but it doesn't work. (Simplified)

```
int i;
int len=4;

union dummy{
    float f32;
    uint32_t u32;
    uint8_t u8[4];
};

union dummy inst1[len]; //First instance on source uC
union dummy inst2[len]; //Second instance on target uC


inst1[0].u8[0]=73;
inst1[1].f32=17.5;
//... and so on

printf("Source: %d, %f\n",inst1[0].u8[0],inst1[1].f32);

//Prepare SPI uint8_t array
uint8_t spi_arr[4*len];

*spi_arr=*inst1; //Wrong. What to do here?

//SPI uint8_t array arrived on target. Convert it back to union type

*inst2=*spi_arr; //Wrong. What to do here?

printf("Target: %d, %f\n",inst2[0].u8[0],inst2[1].f32);
```

It gives me the error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' from type 'union dummy'
```

All I want is just copy the content of the arrays forth and back as they are. How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example program that shows how to use pointers to access your data as two different types:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int len = 4;

union dummy{
    float f32;
    uint32_t u32;
    uint8_t u8[4];
};

int main(void) {
    union dummy inst1[len]; //First instance on source uC
    union dummy *inst2; //Second instance on target uC
    uint8_t *spi_arr;

    for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        for (int inner_index = 0; inner_index < 4; inner_index++) {
            inst1[index].u8[inner_index] = '1' + inner_index;
        }
    }

    spi_arr = (uint8_t *) inst1;

    for (int index = 0; index < sizeof(inst1); index++) {
        printf("%c", spi_arr[index]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");

    inst2 = (union dummy *) spi_arr;

    for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        for (int inner_index = 0; inner_index < 4; inner_index++) {
            printf("%c", inst2[0].u8[inner_index]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1234123412341234

1234
1234
1234
1234
```

Answer (score 1):

This an example program showing how to copy your data to a `char` array and back again using `memcpy`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

const int len = 4;

union dummy{
    float f32;
    uint32_t u32;
    uint8_t u8[4];
};

int main(void) {
    union dummy inst1[len]; //First instance on source uC
    union dummy inst2[len]; //Second instance on target uC
    uint8_t spi_arr[sizeof(inst1)];

    for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        for (int inner_index = 0; inner_index < 4; inner_index++) {
            inst1[index].u8[inner_index] = '1' + inner_index;
        }
    }

    memcpy(spi_arr, inst1, sizeof(inst1));
    memcpy(inst2, spi_arr, sizeof(spi_arr));

    for (int index = 0; index < len; index++) {
        for (int inner_index = 0; inner_index < 4; inner_index++) {
            printf("%c", inst2[index].u8[inner_index]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
1234
1234
1234
1234
```

Comment: Well I didn't want to use memcpy. I wished this is simply working setting the pointer of the union to the arrived char array. Somehow disappointing.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the line:

```
*spi_arr=*inst1; //Wrong. What to do here?
```

to read:

```
*spi_arr=inst1[0].u8[0];
```

It compiles. I'm not sure if that's what you want. The data types should match to do a pointer assignment, which is what the error message tells you. In this example, both `*spi_arr` and `inst1[0].u8[0]` are of the *unit8_t* type.

Comment: Ok, but this way you can't copy back like: inst2[0].u8[0]=*spi_arr; This will copy only one item.